# CS1106 Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been working on a project in WPF C# and I'm trying to animate an image to move down. I have found the "MoveTo" function on the Internet and when I pasted it in the code the error occurred.

```
Public partial class Window1: Window
{
    public static int w = 1;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void MoveTo(this Image target, double newY)
    {
        var top = Canvas.GetTop(target);
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        target.RenderTransform = trans;
        DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(top, newY - top, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim1);
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveTo(image, 130);
    }
}
```

What I need to do to fix this?

Comment: in this particular case you shouldn't use keyword `this` in method declaration here: `(this Image target`; -> `(Image target, double newY)`

Comment: What kind of an error? Attach a log file or something...

Comment: @MarkoLetic a CS1106. It says so in the title.

Comment: Remove the Static from your int w = 1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> public void MoveTo(this Image target, double newY)

`this` on the first argument of a method definition indicates an extension method which, as the error message says, only makes sense on a non-generic static class. Your class isn't static.

This doesn't seem to be something that makes sense as an extension method, since it's acting on the instance in question, so remove the `this`.

Comment: you saved my day, was working on a large update of a class and suddenly the error turned up, i was kinda sure decoration of the clas wasnt changed, but some routine had changed it.. kinda weird that this error doesnt show up at the location of the function using "this"

Answer (score 1):

MoveTo is an extension method - it's just a syntactic sugar for a static function, so you can call

```
image.MoveTo(2.0)
```

instead of

```
SomeUtilityClass.MoveTo(image, 2.0)
```

However extension methods must be placed in a static class, so you cannot place it in your Window class. You can just omit "this" keyword in the declaration and use it like a static method or you need to move the method to a static class.

Comment: Upvoted for actually taking the time to explain what an Extension Class is.

Answer (score 1):

Please google first next time

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397656.aspx

Extension methods needs to be defined in a static class.
Remove the this keyword from the method signature "MoveTo".

this:

```
public void MoveTo(this Image target, double newY)
```

should be like this:

```
public void MoveTo(Image target, double newY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add keyword static to class declaration:

```
public static class ClassName{}
```

Comment: You can't make WPF window class static.